# Serialize inherited classes using protobuf-net

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization, protobuf-net

I have a problem serializing derived classes using protobuf-net. I don't know if it is because it is not supported, or I am doing something wrong.

I have a generic base class (which I can serialize directly) and then i make a specialization of this, but this one I can't serialize. The following is the code for the two classes and a example of usage. Am i doing something wrong?

**Edit**

Added restriction to the generic types

**Base**

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
public class Base<TKey, TValue>
    where TKey : Key
    where TValue : Key
{
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
    public Dictionary<TKey, Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> Data { get; set; }
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2)]
    public TValue DefaultValue { get; set; }

    public Base()
    {
        this.Data = new Dictionary<TKey, Dictionary<TKey, TValue>>();
    }

    public Base(TValue defaultValue)
        : this()
    {
        this.DefaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public TValue this[TKey x, TKey y]
    {
        get
        {
            try { return this.Data[x][y]; }
            catch { return this.DefaultValue; }
        }
        set
        {
            if (!this.Data.ContainsKey(x))
                this.Data.Add(x, new Dictionary<TKey, TValue> { { y, value } });
            else
                this.Data[x][y] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Key class**

```
public abstract class Key
{
}
```

**Specialized key**

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
public class IntKey : Key
{
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public IntKey() { }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, this)) return true;

        var s = obj as IntKey;
        return this.Value.Equals(s.Value);
    }
}
```

**Specialized class**

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
public class IntWrapper<TKey> : Base<TKey, IntKey>
    where TKey : Key
{
    public IntWrapper()
        : base() { }

    public IntWrapper(IntKey defaultValue)
        : base(defaultValue) { }
}
```

**An example of usage**

```
var path = @"C:\Temp\data.dat";
var data = new IntWrapper<IntKey>(new IntKey { Value = 0 }); // This will not be serialized
for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    for(var y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        data[new IntKey { Value = x }, new IntKey { Value = y }] = new IntKey { Value = x + y };
}

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(fileStream, data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model needs to understand *in proto terms* the relationship between base-type and sub-type, in particular the field used to uniquely identify it. Usually this would be done with attributes on the base type, but this is problematic when using generics, because you can't use `typeof(SomeType<TKey>)` in an attribute. You *can* define this at runtime, though:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof (Base<int,int>), true)
              .AddSubType(3, typeof (IntWrapper<int>));
```

After that, it works.

Comment: Okay, what if i limit the scope of the generic type to inherit from a certain abstract class (I added this to the Q). So now the base structure only allows types that are of type `Key` will this make it easier?

Comment: @aweis would need to see a concrete example; but: most **common** scenarios can be handled with `[ProtoInclude(...)]`

Comment: The example is pretty much the code in the question. My biggest problem is that I have no control over what types there are given to the base class, but I can require them to be serializable, so I thought that limiting them to inherit a specific base class would also limiting the scope!

Comment: @aweis protobuf-net, in common with things like XmlSerializer, likes the structure to be known ahead of time... it isn't designed to serialize completely unpredictable types

Comment: Okay, then I will do some redesigning. Thanks.